# QML app icon not effective when called from app.setWindowIcon()

Tags: unity, application-development, icons, ubuntu-touch, qml

I've a Qt5/QML hybrid app built with Ubuntu Touch SDK. I'm trying to set the app icon for it, but without success. Code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer; // is this part of the problem perhaps?
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(...);  // works and i see my page
    ...
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon::("./localfilepath.svg");
    ...

    return app.exec();
}
```

It clearly looks for the svg (changing the path generates an error), but this doesn't change the icon used when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or look at the side bar icon (a ? icon).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17357